# Solutions to extract similar sets from a list of sets

Tags: java, set

Suppose we have 5 sets :

```
A1 = {field1, field2, field3}
A2 = {field1, field2, field3}
A3 = {field1, field2, field4}
A4 = {field1, field5, field6}
A5 = {field5, field6, field4}
```

Im searching fo a java method to retrieve a result like the following :

1 - Exact sets

```
A1 = {field1, field2, field3} & A2 = {field1, field2, field3}
```

2 - Similar sets with 1 field difference

```
A1 = {field1, field2, field3} & A3 = {field1, field2, field4}
A4 = {field1, field5, field6} & A5 = {field5, field6, field4}
A2 = {field1, field2, field3} & A3 = {field1, field2, field4}
```

3 - Similar sets with 2 fields difference

```
A1 = {field1, field2, field3} & A4 = {field1, field5, field6}
A2 = {field1, field2, field3} & A4 = {field1, field5, field6}
A3 = {field1, field2, field4} & A4 = {field1, field5, field6}
A3 = {field1, field2, field4} & A5 = {field5, field6, field4}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet that we could help with?

Comment: *Method:* Nested loops, aka simple brute-force. What's difficult about trying that?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { for (int j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) { int diff = 0; for (var value : A[i]) { if (! A[j].contains(value)) { diff++; } } /*print here*/ } }`

Comment: Why does `2 -Similar sets with 1 field difference` not include `A2 & A3`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a java set data structure (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-in-java/), then methods A1.retainAll(A2) will perform an intersection between A1 and A2 and then you can use the A1.size() to return the number of similar fields.

The following function would return the number of different elements between two sets.

```java
public int diff(Set<E> A, Set<E> B){
  if(A.size() > B.size()){
    B.retainAll(A);
    return A.size()-B.size();
  }else{
    A.retainAll(B);
    return B.size()-A.size();
  }
}
```

Then you could just check for every pair of sets.

E.g. For exact sets, you only want pairs of sets where the function returns 0;